# which file is explorer.exe equivalent in ubuntu .?

Tags: 13.10, interface

On disabling explorer.exe file in windows, we disable the click events as well as the desktop icons and all other interface facilities are disabled.

Is there any file in ubuntu which disables these interface facilities in ubuntu?

Comment: So you want to remove any file manager abilities from the users in your system?

Comment: Why don't you just install Ubuntu Server instead of Ubuntu Desktop? It comes without GUI by default.

Comment: @BrunoPereira : exacly i want to disable the interface and file manager facility from ubntu

Answer (score 2):

Explorer's equivalent is Nautilus in standard Ubuntu. It manages the file browsing and desktop. Unity is rendered out by Compiz, which is separate though.

Your simplest route for disabling all of that, is to just use a different session and Window Manager. Something like OpenBox or even NoDM (if you're just running one application). It'll mean you need to get under the hood and work out how window managers work... But that's a damned sight easier than ripping out functionality of Nautilus.

Comment: I am new to this Ubuntu interface but, I want to run just a single application. will you please elaborate the working of NoDM or OpenBox or can u please share a link with me ? this would be very helpful for me. Also please if you have link or idea about stopping the Nautilus and restricting the interface please do suggest me with that